# php disable code parsing for a few lines in a statement

Tags: php

In php, you got to echo each and every line of html, is there a way to specify the end tag:
?>
in a if statement?

ex:

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 1)
{
?><html><body><strong>HELLO WORLD</body></html><?php
//continue executing code
}
```

is that even possible? I really hope it is, as it is really annoying to echo each and every line of code.

Also, could someone think of a better title? If someone has the same problem as me I would love for him/her to find the solution.

Comment: You can do this, but it definitely makes a mess out of your code.  If you have a fairly small amount of things to echo out, use echo.  Otherwise, consider a template engine.

Comment: you can use multi-line print statements instead of echoing every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously haven't bothered just trying this before asking here.

Yes, it works.

Comment: sorry, didn't think it would work. I shouldn't have been so lazy.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php if(1):?>

<html><body><strong>HELLO WORLD</body></html>

<?php endif;?>`

more tidy code~~